# Argparse : Formatting arguments

Tags: python, argparse

I want to pass the arguments in various ways like :

```
python abc.py 1 2
python abc.py -d 3 
python abc.py -c 6
```

I have tried with subparsers but i could do with

```
python abc.py def 1 2
python abc.py spec -d 3
python abc.py spec -c 6
```

is this possible ?

Comment: The question is too broad. Can you give a specific example? Like how would you like to use those command line arguments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need subparser in your case. Something like this should be fine:

```
import argparse


parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-d', type=int, nargs='?')
parser.add_argument('-c', type=int, nargs='?')
parser.add_argument('args', type=int, nargs='*')

print(parser.parse_args())
```

Which results in:

```
$python3 test_argparse.py 1 2                                                 
Namespace(args=[1, 2], c=None, d=None)                                                                           
$python3 test_argparse.py -d 3
Namespace(args=[], c=None, d=3)
$python3 test_argparse.py -c 6
Namespace(args=[], c=6, d=None)
```

If you want the options to be mutually exclusive `argparse` provides a [mutually exclusive group](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.add_mutually_exclusive_group). Unfortunately positionals are always considered as required and hence you must manually check for them if you don't want the user to use them when specifying a given option (however I believe in this case you are provided a bad interface to your command).

Comment: For this bare specification, the default `nargs` is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

In `argparse.add_argument` you can provide the argument text not as a string, but as a list of strings, so having mulltiple forms of the same argument. 
Browse [argparse docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html) carefully - this module can do everything you need.

Answer (score 0):

A parser with two `optionals` of type `int`, and a `positional` with `nargs='*‘`, would accept your 3 inputs. Do you have any more constraints on the inputs?